# Overwrite single row excel information based on Unique ID in column data

Tags: excel, matlab

Each time when I execute some functions I am storing the results in an excel file. Rows of column one contains unique ID for each subject. Whenever I execute the function new results are automatically appended into a new row. Whenever the same information is executed, I would like to overwrite rows containing unique ID information with a warning sign such as “The information is already exists would you like to overwrite them” etc.  I tried this with “unique” function in matlab but no success. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

My code so far is as below:

```
LastName = {'Sam';'John';'Bella';'Diana';'Kelly'};
Age = [48;53;58;80;29];
Smoker = logical([1;0;1;0;1]);
Height = [61;59;64;69;62];
Weight = [126;153;141;153;129];
BloodPressure = [104 95; 119 79; 115 85; 127 85; 112 81];
Table = table(LastName,Age,Smoker,Height,Weight,BloodPressure)
writetable(Table,"BP_Analysis.xlsx","WriteMode","append","AutoFitWidth",false);

%Overwirte the rows "Lastname" if same results are executed again. 
data = readtable('BP_Analysis.xlsx','PreserveVariableName', true);
data.Properties.VariableNames{1} = 'Lastname';
[~,idx]=unique(strcat('Lastname','rows'));
```

I would like to overwrite all the information in any rows if the data with same lastname is executed again. I have created a dummy problem to reflect my original data.

Answer (score 1):

With the xlsx file from the snippet above, you could do this:

If the LastName in the new row is, let's say 'Sam', then:

```
newLastName = 'Sam';
idx = contains(data.LastName, newLastName)
```

Now, idx will contain the row indices of all the existing entries that match with 'Sam', and so you could then index into them to overwrite, add a warning, and so on.

```
if any(idx)
    % throw warning, ...
end

for j = 1:numel(idx)
    if idx(j) == 1
        % replace the row:
        data(j, :) = % ...
    end
end
```

Comment: You could use `for j = find(idx(:).')` to loop over the indices where `idx` is true, and remove the nested `if` condition.

Comment: Hi "akamath" and "Wolfe" thanks  for your answers and help. I will update my code as per your suggestions. Kind regards